# Python script not running with local web server, just displays code in browser

Tags: python, apache

I have spent hours banging my head against the wall on this one!

I am running Python 2.7.10 on a Mac. I have a few Python scripts that I have written which run inside the Atom editor.

I have been trying to run these scripts on a local web server to speed up development.  I have tried MAMP (which just throws 500 Internal Server Errors), and now "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" which just displays the python code in the browser and doesn't seem to execute it.

I have chmod +x my .py files.  I start the web server in the folder that contains the .py files.

Here is an example...

hello.py

`print("hello world")`

When I browse to http://localhost:8000/hello.py I get the raw code displayed in the browser.

> print("hello world")

If I use terminal and enter "python hello.py" it runs and displays the correct output...

> MacBook-Pro-3:folder dj$ python hello.py
>
> hello world

I have tried dozens of tutorials and suggested solutions, but none seem to help. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks!

D

Comment: `SimpleHTTPServer` can't do that, try `CGIHTTPServer` instead which can execute scripts if placed in the right directory. A better approach would be to go back to an Apache server and configure it properly (this isn't a topic for Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server that `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (or, for future readers, `python -m http.server` on Python 3) spins will not execute *any* file. It is merely a server that *serves* files as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) suggests:

> The SimpleHTTPServer module can be used in the following manner in order to set up a **very basic web server serving files** relative to the current directory.

In order to get a server that will actually execute Python code, you'll need to use another tool. I'd start with [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Had a feeling I was missing something quite fundamental! Many thanks, I now have a "hello world"! :)